# How to relocate source files in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file-structure

Consider the following directory structure:

```
MyProject\VS2010\myproject.sln  
MyProject\VS2010\myproject.csproj  
MyProject\src\SourceFile1.cs  
MyProject\src\SourceFile2.cs
```

When I add a new file to solution in Visual Studio, it is added to `VS2010` folder, however I would like all my source files to be in `src` folder. The only way I know is to unload the project in Visual Studio, move the files manually, then edit `.csproj` file to point to the new location.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I always drag&drop the files in teh Solution Explorer and that always seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can add files to your project without copying them by pressing a little arrow on `Add` button in `Add Existing Item` dialog and selecting `Add as a link`. This will add a file to your project leaving it where it is.

[image: Add as a link]